# Compile-time error while using custom C++ header file - "std_lib_facilities.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm learning using this book - Programming Principles & Practice using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup, 1st edition. The author uses a header file `std_lib_facilities.h` ([here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)) for every program - examples, drill or exercises.

I'm trying to solve this question 13 from chapter 4 -

> Create a program to find all the prime numbers between 1 and 100.
>   There is a classic method for doing this, called the "Sieve of
>   Eratosthenes." U you don't know that method, get on the web and look
>   it up. Write your program using this method.

When I try to compile my program (I'm using Visual Studio 2013), here -

```
// Sieve of Eratosthenes

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int max = 100, i = 0, j = 0, total = 0;
    vector<bool> primes(max + 1, true);

    // Find primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes method
    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;
    for (i = 0; i <= max; ++i){
        if (primes[i] == true){
            for (j = 2; i * j <= max; ++j){
                primes[i * j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Show primes
    cout << "\n\nAll prime numbers from 1 to " << max << " -\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < primes.size(); ++i)
        if (primes[i] == true){
            cout << i << " ";
            ++total;
        }
    cout << "\n\nTotal number of prime numbers == " << total << "\n\n";

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

it shows this error which I'm unable to understand -

```
1>  13_4exercise.cpp
1>c:\users\i$hu\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c++ development\c++ development\13_4exercise.cpp(23): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\i$hu\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c++ development\c++ development\std_lib_facilities.h(88): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vb_reference<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char32_t>>>' to 'bool &'
1>          c:\users\i$hu\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c++ development\c++ development\std_lib_facilities.h(86) : while compiling class template member function 'bool &Vector<bool>::operator [](unsigned int)'
1>          c:\users\i$hu\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c++ development\c++ development\13_4exercise.cpp(11) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool &Vector<bool>::operator [](unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          c:\users\i$hu\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c++ development\c++ development\13_4exercise.cpp(8) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Vector<bool>' being compiled
```

What does this error mean and how to resolve this?

Comment: vector<bool> is a specialization that turned out to be problematic...switch to vector<char>...

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. Can you explain why `vector<bool>` isn't working?

Comment: @marom: Hmm..., but I have a question that initially when I didn't have this header file, I used this - `#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open( char ch; cin >> ch; )`, as suggested by the author in chapter 2, and this code worked fine then. But when I downloaded & replaced this header, that error popped up. So why the code worked then? There has to be some problem with the new file (I know that there are a lot of things in this new file as compared to what I was using before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your library `"std_lib_facilities.h"` is using custom implementation of `vector` which doesn't have [`vector<bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) specialized template.

The specialized template uses `allocator<bool>` with [`vector<bool>::reference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/reference/) as a return value for `operator[]`.

In your case it's using default allocator which is returning `std::_Vb_reference<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char32_t>>>` from `operator[]` - hence your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to add changes to `std_lib_facilities.h` so that I can use `vector<bool>`?

Comment: There are two options:
    
1. implement your own specialized template for vector<bool> with appropriate Reference type
2. comment out vector re-implementation shipped in that library and use the standard one

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the 2nd one, 1st is out of my scope (for now).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to your header.

It will compile if you replace this include with with pure standard headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;  // for learning purpose
```

and replace `keep_window_open()` with `cin.get()`

Comment: Is there any way to add changes to `"std_lib_facilities.h"` so that I can use `vector<bool>`?